# What is nabla scalar (a.u) where a is a scalar field and u a vector field?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

We have a domain D of say R² and a function a from D to R and a function u from R² to R² what is Nabla dot (au) ? If u were from R² to R we could have simply used the product rule

Comment: Please use TeX formatting to make your question easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the question phrased, both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{u}$ are vector valued functions, where the domain of $\vec{a}$ is $D$ and the domain of $\vec{u}$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so I will answer the question under that assumption.  So I believe in that case you are looking for a formula for,
$$ \nabla(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{u})  $$

Try to use calculus you already know on the components.   So say, $\vec{u}=\langle f_1(x,y), g_1(x,y) \rangle$ and $\vec{a}=\langle f_2(x,y),g_2(x,y) \rangle $.  Then,

$$\nabla(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{u})=\nabla(f_1f_2+g_1g_2)=\nabla(f_1f_2)+\nabla(g_1g_2) $$

Now just calculate the above gradients to get a general formula.

Comment: Sorry I meant a is real valued

Comment: That's fine, then you get, $\nabla \cdot (\langle af_1 ,ag_1 \rangle )=\partial_x (af_1)+\partial_y(ag_1)$.  Now you can apply the product rule for partial derivatives to both terms.

Comment: In the above I had $a\vec{u} =\langle af_1 ,ag_1 \rangle$ as in the answer's notation, but I thought I would just write it here explicitly.